# Fullscreen controls position in openlayers map

Tags: html, css, openlayers

I created an openlayers map with the fullscreen controls added. From default they are positioned in the top right, but I would like to have them on the bottom right. A division in my html contains the map with the following code:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="map.js"></script>
```

It is linked to a javascript file with the following code (I left some code out for readability):

```
var map = new ol.Map ({
  target: document.getElementById('map'),
  layers: ...,
  view: ...,
  controls: ...,
    new ol.control.FullScreen(),
    })
 ])
});
```

And finally I have a css file that styles the `div` and is also supposed to move the fullscreen controls to the bottom right:

```
#map {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.ol-full-screen {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  bottom 0px;
}
```

In the css code snippet I use the `position: fixed` for the map and I try to position the fullscreen controls by assigning them an absolute position, but this does not work. The controls do not react to the `bottom` position, but they do react to `left`, `right` and `top` positioning. I also tried setting the map to relative and the controls to absolute (it should work that way for a div inside a div), but this also did not bring the expected result. Instead the map does not fill out the full browserwindow anymore and the controls are still not moveable to the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default setting in ol.css is

```
.ol-full-screen {
  right: .5em;
  top: .5em;
}
```

all control buttons heights are 1.375em

So a top anchored button in the bottom right corner will be

```
.ol-full-screen {
  right: .5em;
  top: calc(100% - 2.375em);
}
```